# Gradle build using sourceSets with the same source files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i'm trying to understand how to use the gradle with the following:
my project need to have 2 different output: 'basic' and 'full'
the only difference between them is that on 'basic' i don't use all java files from the src folder.
In order to do that i've created sourceSets and on the 'basic' set i simply excludes several files.
My problem is that both source sets need to use the same value for the java.srcDirs and when i try to run it on the Android studio i receive an error message that both source sets use the same folder and the build is stopped.

My question is how can i have the same source files on 2 different source sets?
I don't want to split the files to 2 different folders

Regards

Comment: DId you try to define a flavor?

Comment: In my opinion you should use 2 flavors.

Comment: how will it help me to use flavour?
can i exclude files from a flavour?